# Figur of Cone related to the strict, weak and lexicographic order?

Tags: relations, order-theory, lattice-orders, convex-cone

I wrote the definition but I can't find the figure of cone.

In $R^2$ , the cones related  to strict componentwise order, weak component wise order and lexicographic order and max order?

Strict componentwise order : $y^1 <y^2 \iff y_1^k <y_2^k \forall  k=1,2 $

weak component wise order : $y^1\leq y^2 \iff  y_1^k <= y_2^k \forall k=1,2$

lexicographic order : $k^* = min \{k: y_1^k \neq y_2^k\}  $  , $y^1 <_lex y^2 \iff y_1^k* < y_2^k* $ or $y^1=y^2$

Max order: $y^1 <_max y^2 \iff  max y_1^k < max y_2^k$

For all  order we have a related cone , with notation $C_R$ , $C_R=\{y^2-y^1 : y^1 R y^2\} $.

Comment: Whst is a figure of a cone?

Comment: My guess is it would be the 2nd order.

Comment: Figure of cone is a diagram if $C_R$. For example $C_{<=}$  is a non negative orthant in $\mathbb R^n$

Comment: $C_{<=}= \{d=y^1-y^2 \in \mathbb R^n : d_k=y_2^k -y_1^k >=0 , k= 1,2,....,p\}= \mathbb R^n _{>=} $

Comment: So the figure is { d : for all k, d_k >= 0 } = the upper set of {0} by the 2nd order.

Comment: Yes+ diagram $C_R$